# Are all the primes greater than $3$ in form of $6n\pm1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

today I've encountered the following excercise:

Show that all the primes greater than $3$ are in form of $6n\pm1$...

My initial thought was that numbers are in form of $6n,\quad 6n\pm1,\quad 6n\pm2, \quad 6n\pm3$ in respect to $6$ and $6n\pm2=2(3n\pm1),\quad 6n\pm3=3(2n\pm1)$ so since they are multiples of $2$ and $3$ they can't represent primes. This however didn't completely satisfy me, because I've shown that other forms in respect to $6$ aren't primes, but that doesn't necessarily mean that $6n\pm1$ must be prime. I thought perhaps I can do induction but I don't know what inital property to use for a start, or perhaps I am overseeing it right now.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `that doesn't necessarily mean that 6n±1 must be prime` Of course it doesn't, but that's not what the question asked.

Comment: You don't need to prove all $6n\pm1$ are primes (good, because they aren't).

Comment: "but that doesn't necessarily mean that 6n±1 must be prime".  The question asked you to prove all fish (primes > 3) live in water (=6n $\pm$ 1).  It didnt ask you to prove that everything that lives in water is a fish.  Indeed I know of a porpoise (35) that lives underwater (35 = 6x6-1) but is not a fish (35 is not prime).

Comment: ... so to prove that all fish live in water, it is enough to prove everything that lives on land (6n$\pm$2, 6n$\pm$3 or 6n) are not fish.  And as 6n=6n;6n$\pm$2=2(3n$\pm$1) and $6n+3 = 3(n+1)$, they are all not fish.

Comment: To think that a "trusted" user can't find one of the umpteen earlier incarnations of this standard question :-(

Comment: Thank you for all your comments, my apologies for not realising it. Sometimes we miss things, had I realised I wouldn't have posted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are all primes greater than $3$ of the form $6n\pm 1$?

Yes, because the only other forms are $6n$, $6n\pm 2 = 3(2n\pm 1)$ and $6n + 3 = 3(2n+1)$ which can't be primes.

Are all integers of the form $6n\pm 1$ prime? Of course not.  $25 = 4*6+1; 35=6*6-1;49=6*8+1$ etc. show they are not.

Were you asked to prove that all primes greater than $3$ are of the form $6n\pm 1$?  Yes, you were.  Did you?  Yes, you did.

Were you asked to prove that everything of the form $6n \pm 1$ was a prime?  No, you were not.  Were you able to?  No, you couldn't.  Can anyone? No, because it isn't true.  Were you expected to? No, you were not because it isn't true.

Answer (score 3):

It's because $6n+3$ is divisible by $3$

(and obviously, $6n$, $6n+2$, and $6n+4$ are all divisible by $2$)

So any prime must be of the form $6n+1$ or $6n+5$ (i.e. $6n-1$) ... which of course does *not* mean that all such numbers *are* primes .. but that wasn't the question.